# Trouble counting peaks in 1D array

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, statistics

I want to read a .txt file and get the data from it, and then come up with a way to find out how many peaks there are in a certain chunk of it. I have a Geiger counter which will run for a certain time and its output will be recorded in a file, which I'll call 'NuclearCounting.txt'. You can see the first hundred lines [here](http://pastebin.com/D6sSLUYR). You can see that the mean is about ~1.7 and rarely spikes to ~3 or drops to ~1.

I want to then break the data into chunks of either a minute or a second (in this case I choose seconds) and analyse how many 'events' occur in each time interval. I do that by calling an 'event' a max or min of the data. There is some noise due to background radiation, so I would like to have a line in there that says a 'peak' must be something which differs from the mean by 3 s.d. if possible.

Here is the code so far:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy import signal
import scipy.stats
x1 = []
y1 = []
f = open("NC.txt", "r")
for line in f:
   line = line.strip()
   parts = line.split(",")  #Separated by commas and spaces
   time = float(parts[1])  #This column is the column recording time
   value = float(parts[2]) #This one records the value the detector reads.
   x1.append(time)
   y1.append(value)
f.close()

xv = np.array(x1) #Time
yv = np.array(y1) #Values recorded

#Statistics
m = np.mean(yv)
d = np.std(yv)
timetot = int(round(np.max(xv))) #This gives the total time in seconds to the nearest second. I use this to break it into chunks of one second of data each.
#Counting events
def chunk(l, n):
    n = max(1, n)
    return [l[k:k+n] for k in range(0, len(l), n)]
t = chunk(xv,timetot) #Breaking the time into chunks of a second
v = chunk(yv,timetot) #Doing the same for the values recorded by the detector
i = []
for x in v: 
   peak = signal.find_peaks_cwt(x, np.arange(2,10)) #This is the problem area
   i.append(peak)
print(len(i))
```

The array i is used to store the number of 'peaks' I get. I just want to know the length of i for each interval. The problem is that the output is python tells me I have 25000 peaks. That makes no sense. Per second, I should be only getting a few counts at the maximum. It also just gives me an array which had entries entirely of 15.

Can someone please tell me how to correct this? I have no idea why the scipy function shouldn't work, and certainly not why it should spit out 15 when no data entry has that value.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The list `i` in your code doesn't store the number of peaks per chunk but the peaks indices.

In order to count the peaks you would need to use `i.append(len(peak))`. If you want to also constrain the peaks to be 3 standard deviations greater than the median you can do `peak = np.sum(x[signal.find_peaks_cwt(x, np.arange(2,10))] > 3*d)`.

Last but not least `print(len(i))` will return the length of your peaks list, i.e. the amount of chunks. I think what you want is rather to find out the number of peaks per chunk. So, to sum it all up I think this is what you want.

```
for x in v: 
   peak_index = signal.find_peaks_cwt(x, np.arange(2,10))
   peak_sum = np.sum(x[peak_index] > 3*d)
   i.append(peak_sum)
for p in i:
    print(p)
```

Comment: That's perfect, exactly the right fix for me. This is just a minor thing, but as I understand scipy.find_peaks_cwt, the np.arange(a,b) part basically specifies the width of the peak, doesn't it?

Comment: That's also the way I understand. Although I have to admit for your case I'd use [`signal.argrelmax()`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.16.0/reference/generated/scipy.signal.argrelmax.html#scipy.signal.argrelmax)